# How to display the bit pattern of a Structure variable in C which uses bit fields?

Tags: c, struct, bit-fields

```
    Struct some{
         unsigned int a:5;
         Unsigned int b:6;
    } std1;
```

Now let us have stored some values in std1. Now how can we display the bit pattern of the structure variable std1 in C?

Comment: Thank you for the immediate reply, can you please provid me the code for how to copy std1 to the union by assigning to the struct some member.

Comment: also i'm restricted to use any other header files then stdio.h,stdlib.h and malloc.h,so uint8_t* provide an error.  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any data type in C, you can inspect its raw binary contents by iterating over it using character type pointers. Example:

```
const uint8_t* ptr = (const uint8_t*)&std1;
for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof std1; i++)
{
  printf("%.2X ", (unsigned int)ptr[i]);
}
```

(`uint8_t` will always be a character type in all real world systems except on some dysfunctional legacy DSPs that shouldn't be used for any purpose.)

Comment: As iam limited to  use the stdlib.h,stdio.h and malloc.h. It shows an compiler error,can you please tell me any other method .Thanks for the help @Lundin

Comment: @AndrewAllen I didn't test this code. Did you include stdint.h? Otherwise, if that's not possible, simply switch `uint8_t` for `unsigned char`.

Comment: no i didn't include the stdint. then i use unsigned char instead of uint_8 and i got the hexadecimal values as output(is that my ans?)  @lundin Thanks for the help.